# very slow wordpress theme DOMcontentLoaded takes 6sec

Tags: wordpress, performance, domcontentloaded

i have a wordpress site [Migau](http://www.migau.com) and it loads very slowly.
I did a speed test and this the result came back with a 6 sec load of my DOMcontentloaded.

Can anyone help with this matter 
Thanks

Comment: Who is your host?  If it's not a commercial/business grade host, 6 seconds actually isn't that bad.  Even most business class hosts take a couple seconds without the help of a CDN, or caching of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My host is one.com. Still it takes like the full 7.5 sec to load the page, that's way to long. I have other wordpress sites that load alot faster also on one.com.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable Gzip?

According to the Google PageSpeed browser extension, enabling gzip would reduce file size (of the plain text files which can be compressed) by 74%.

Also, try consolidating external resources (CSS and JS) to reduce HTTP requests. More info from the [Yahoo Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Along the same lines, I like to utilize jQuery from the Google CDN (with a local fallback) as this increases the chances of it being cached, and your Google Webfont requests should likely be consolidated.

I also usually use a caching plugin like W3 Total Cache to speed things up a bit.